# veracript install script fails if run from script

Tags: linux, bash

I am dokerising veracryp and need to run the install script in non-interactive mode. To run script I need to pass it answers that are asked by the script,  if run in interactive mode. problem is if I pass answer by command piping or from the file I get the error:

```
    echo -e "1\n\nq\ny\ny\n\n" | /opt/tdp/veracrypt-1.23-setup-console-x64 
    Verifying archive integrity...  100%  
    All good. Uncompressing VeraCrypt 1.23 Installer  100% 
    Error: Terminal required
```

If I run the same script without piping the script works OK.

I narrowed down the problem to this line

https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/blob/a108db7c85248a3b61d0c89c086922332249f518/src/Setup/Linux/veracrypt_install_template.sh#L49

The problem is that the line of code is evaluated differently depending on if the script is run by piping or by its own,  this line:

https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/blob/a108db7c85248a3b61d0c89c086922332249f518/src/Setup/Linux/veracrypt_install_template.sh#L23

```
tty >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && TTY=1
```

To insolate the problem I created this dummy scrip

```
A=0
tty >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && A=1

echo "A is"
echo $A
echo
```

if you name this script inst.sh and run it twice, with and without pipe you will get different results

```
# echo xxx | ./inst.sh
A is
0

# ./inst.sh
A is
1
```

Any idea why? This may help me solve veracript problem (I cannot change veracript install script)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done this kind of automation using [expect](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/expect.1.html) (is  a  program  that  "talks" to other interactive programs according to a script)

You will need to install it in your docker image if not present.

You will need to create an expect script with the question prompts and answers for each.

In a `install-vera-crypt.exp` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
spawn /opt/tdp/veracrypt-1.23-setup-console-x64
expect "The text you expect to answer 1\r"
send -- "1\r"
expect "The text you expect to answer q\r"
send -- "q\r"

...

expect eof
```

Then you can execute it with: `expect -f install-vera-crypt.exp`

Comment: complete file is actually slightly different

`#!/usr/bin/expect -f`

`set timeout -1`
`spawn /opt/tdp/veracrypt-1.23-setup-console-x64`
`expect "To select, enter 1 or 2:"`
`send -- "1\r"`
`expect "Press Enter to display the license terms..."`
`send -- "\r"`
`expect ":"`
`send -- "q\r"`
`expect "Do you accept and agree to be bound by the license terms?"`
send -- "yes\r"
expect "Press Enter to exit..."
send -- "\r"
expect eof`

Answer (score 0):

Gonzalo Matheu has successfully answered the question, many thanks. I just posting here slightly altered version of the file that worked for me

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
spawn /opt/tdp/veracrypt-1.23-setup-console-x64
expect "To select, enter 1 or 2:"
send -- "1\r"
expect "Press Enter to display the license terms..."
send -- "\r"
expect ":"
send -- "q\r"
expect "Do you accept and agree to be bound by the license terms?"
send -- "yes\r"
expect "Press Enter to exit..."
send -- "\r"
expect eof
```